# hadoop sqoop error while importing data using options file

Tags: sqoop

i am new to hadoop and while practicing sqoop i have got this error message , the command i have used is 
i created an `import.txt` file and in that i used 
`import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopdb --username hadoop -P` and placed this file on HDFS.

while importing i have given this file to the sqoop tool using the `--options-file` command. so the final command i have given at the command promt is as follows,

```
sqoop --options-file /user/cloudera/import.txt --table employee
```

after hiting the enter key i have got the following error message

```
   sqoop --options-file /user/cloudera/import.txt --table employee
    13/10/16 13:43:12 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Error while expanding arguments




java.lang.Exception: Unable to read options file: /user/cloudera/import.txt
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:102)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:33)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:201)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/cloudera/import.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:55)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.OptionsFileUtil.expandArguments(OptionsFileUtil.java:70)
    ... 4 more
Unable to read options file: /user/cloudera/import.txt
```

can anyone tell me why the error is coming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have u checked the read and execute permission of the file for the user?

Answer (score 2):

--option-file path should be local directory. Don't use HDFS directory.

```
 sqoop --options-file /home/cloudera/import.txt --table employee
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. I solved it using the following approach.
In the options file you have to mention tools,commands and their arguments line by line

In your case, Your options file "import.txt" should be created like this

```
$cat > import.txt
import
--connect
jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopdb
--username
hadoop
-P
```

After you created the options file, you can use this to import the table

```
sqoop --options-file /user/cloudera/import.txt --table employee
```

Hope this works. Key is you have to mention tools and arguments line by line.
For more understanding on this refer this link

[Sqoop User Guide by Apache.org](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html)

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Calling Sqoop from Oozie and you are facing the same issue -Unable to read options file.

Then you need place the option-file inside workflow location and specify the file in sqoop action-files and also you need to change the permission for that file to chmod 674(When workflow is running in oozie, it will run with sqoop user so it is mandatory to change permission).

This will resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I put option file in local directory, It worked.
Also
Argument and value should in different line.
like

--where 
'sal > 5000'

and not like
--where 'sal > 5000'

Answer (score 0):

```
[cloudera@quickstart sqoop]$ sqoop --options-file 
/home/cloudera/Desktop/SqoopOptions.txt --table departments --username root --
password cloudera -m 1 --target-dir jan1301
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
No such sqoop tool: import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera. See 'sqoop help'.
```

I have received above error when I define the SqoopOptions.txt file data in a single line.

The issue resolved when i define each parameter & value in different line like below.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying on single node cluster, option file can be placed under local file system. 
your option file should be like this.

import

--connect

"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"

--username root

-P

for each parameter there should be a next line space.

once you saved the option file then use below command.

sqoop --options-file "your optionfile location" --table abc

hope this should work as this option is perfectly working for me.

Thanks,
Suresh.